# How does $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \vec{x} = \vec{0} \rightarrow \vec{x} = S\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Where S is a constant in the title.

1. I understand that the statement in the title means, $\vec{x}$ can be any scalar of $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$, but where did $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ come from?... Do I need to reduce $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ to RREF...?
2. I also understand how to work out Linear combinations, which I verified on symbolab is correct.

[image]

3. Qn: How did Trefor Bazett(instructor) end up up with $S\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$? Please can someone show me the steps?

For context, I'm trying to relearn foundation while coming across [this part of the video](https://youtu.be/4u55V_Yp-QI?t=237):
[image]

Comment: The equation $(x,x)=(0,0)$ is the same as $x=0$. Then $(x,y)=(0,y)=y(0,1)$ and you can write $S=y$.

Comment: Thanks @mr_e_man, do I need to change it to RREF form in this case(when is the helpful?), and would it still work?

Comment: It's up to your teacher whether you need to put this in reduced row-echelon form. Your teacher probably won't mind if you don't give the RREF explicitly, as long as you explain your reasoning.

Comment: Thanks @1Rock & mr_e_man, I've put the reasoning below, do you mind verifying that my understanding is correct, or if there's an even simpler way to derive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \vec{x} = \vec{0}
$$
This can also be written out in a more expanded form as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, if one goes through all of the proper matrix operations on the left-hand-side, as you've done in your main post, we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and therefore we are looking for solutions where:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which means that $x_1=0$ is strictly defined.  However, what does that say about our vector $\vec{x}$?  Well, if we plug in the $x_1=0$ that we specifically know:
$$
\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
then we are still left with a variable $x_2$ that is not strictly defined but yet will always satisfy the equation no matter what value we give it.
Matching to the form given in the problem then simply involves dividing the entire vector by a scalar to get it on the outside (and renaming it $x_2\to S$).

Comment: Amazing, your explanation is more comprehensive than mine. Will upvote and select this as the right answer for the benefit of future purveyors of linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mr_e_man & @1Rock. I believe the steps are:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \vec{x} = \vec{0} \rightarrow RREF: 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \vec{x} = \vec{0} \to x_1 = 0$.

***The key*** seem to be, that we must express $\vec{x}$ in terms of $x_2$.
And since $x_2$ is a free column, the value of $x_2$ can be any real number.

thus, $\vec{x}=x_2 \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}
\to 
\vec{x} = S\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$
. This is achieved by replacing $x_2$  with S.

Comment: This is essentially correct. I wouldn't say "we must express $\vec{x}$ in terms of $x_2$", I'd say "Because there are more variables than constraints (i.e. more variables than linearly independent rows), we have to express the answer in terms of a free variable $s$" (it's conventional to use lowercase for real variables). As you say, since $x_2$ corresponds to a free column (it's not a column, it's a variable, but it corresponds to a column), the value of $x_2$ can be any real number.

Comment: ... Thus, the solution set is given by your expression. It's not the only way to write it, you could also say $\vec{x}=s\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Ah got it, thank you @1Rock